# 'ESM packages (accessor-fn) in react-force-graph needs to be imported' inconsistency

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, node-modules, package.json

I am receiving a module not found error:

```
Module not found: ESM packages (accessor-fn) need to be imported. Use 'import' to reference the package instead. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/import-esm-externals

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/3d-force-graph-vr/dist/3d-force-graph-vr.mjs
./node_modules/react-force-graph/dist/react-force-graph.mjs
./components/App/analytics/BalancesAndTransactions/HistoricTransactions.tsx
./components/App/analytics/BalancesAndTransactions/BalancesAndTransactions.tsx
./app/app/analytics/page.tsx
```

Basically, I am aware that it is using require to import the package instead of `import` and `from`. The reason I am posting this question is because I have been able to run `react-force-graph` in another application using the same package and Next version. So why would require be working in one Next app and not the other? Is it because a dependency clash or something else? For context, here is my installed dependencies on the broken Next app:

````
"dependencies": {
        "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.7.1",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
        "@moralisweb3/next": "^2.22.2",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
        "@mui/material": "^5.13.5",
        "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
        "@types/node": "20.2.5",
        "@types/react": "18.2.7",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
        "@types/react-sparklines": "^1.7.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "ethers": "^6.6.0",
        "framer-motion": "^10.12.16",
        "mongodb": "^5.6.0",
        "moralis": "^2.22.2",
        "next": "^13.4.5",
        "next-auth": "^4.22.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.21",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-force-graph": "^1.43.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
        "react-sparklines": "^1.7.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7",
        "typescript": "5.0.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2"
    }
    ```

I have tried reinstalling the package, deleting yarn.lock, package.json and node modules. I have also tried using react-force-graph-3d as an alternative, but that also has an issue in it's package dependencies.
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.